# Pause updating formulas in excel

Tags: excel, vba, macos, excel-formula

I am looking for a way to prevent formulas in my spreadsheet from automatically updating unless I trigger them. This is a massive spreadsheet with literally millions of formulas that all attempt to update every time any cell is updated, which lags out my system a lot. I was hoping to create what I imagine will likely be a vba macro which will disable formulas from updating entirely, and add a button which can be pressed to then force formulas to update.

If this is not possible (I am finally learning that excel has more limitations that I first thought), I could then use some advice on how to potentially smooth the formula updating process. There is no way to trim the program or reduce the number of formulas present, and using multiple sheets to communicate would just make everything look too sloppy. Any advice is appreciated, though a direct answer to the first paragraph is preferred.

Comment: Sounds like you need non-volatile alternatives to volatile functions.

Comment: *'Volatile functions recalculate whenever anything in the entire workbook changes, not just when something that affects their outcome changes. Examples of volatile functions are INDIRECT, OFFSET, TODAY, NOW, RAND and RANDBETWEEN. Some sub-functions of the CELL and INFO worksheet functions will make them volatile as well.'* And if a volatile function is within a range referenced by a non-volatile function, the non-volatile recals as well.

Comment: You can set calculation of formulas to manual for a worksheet ... Here's a link ... https://support.office.com/en-us/article/change-formula-recalculation-iteration-or-precision-73fc7dac-91cf-4d36-86e8-67124f6bcce4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try : Formulas > Calculation options > Manual .

Hope that helps. (:

Comment: That worked perfectly, don't know why this was so hard to find on google. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can go to  *Excel Options> Formulas > Calculation options > Manual* .

When you want to update the formulas just click **F9** button which will manually update all the formulas.

I hope this Helps